# How do I set the timeout for a JAX-WS webservice client (javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout) on JBoss VM client configuration?

Tags: web-services, jboss

I know this can be done programatically using the code below:

((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", "300000");

But I don't have rights to change the application code. Then I'm trying to do this at the Jboss configuration (VM client).

Comment: The system isn't using Apache CXF Framework, but the native "javax.xml.ws".